# Can we install Android OS on any Windows Phone and vice versa, and same with iPhone and vice versa?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7, smartphone

I have 3 smartphones with me , one running Windows Mobile OS , another one running Android OS , and 3rd one running iOS.

I am wondering if i can load/install Android OS on any Windows Phone and vice versa, and same with iPhone and vice versa ? To clarify more i am actually trying to load a different OS to any smartphone hardware device, is it possible ?

Comment: Windows Phone is not the same as Windows Mobile. Which one do you have?

Comment: It's easier to just have all three devices.

Comment: Please see [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6849/1465) on the Android SE site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, For installing **Android on Windows phone**, I think you can..(But your window phone has required configuration to run Android) (For other I don't know If I will then surely post here)

Just go through these links,

[Run Android on Your Windows Mobile Phone](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20703/run-android-on-your-windows-mobile-phone/)

[full tutorial on how to put android on windows mobile touch pro 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfxPjGO3LQk)

[How to install Android on most Windows Mobile phones](http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/09/how-to-install-android-on-most-windows-mobile-phones/)

**Update:**

For **Windows 7 to Android** device, this also possible, (You need to do some hack for this)

Just go through these links,

[Install Windows Phone 7 Mango on HTC HD2 [How-To Guide]](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/install-windows-phone-7-mango-on-htc-hd2-how-to-guide/)

[HTC HD2: How To Install WP7 (Windows Phone 7) & MAGLDR 1.13 To NAND](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nac3Fnf-lY4)

[Install windows phone 7 on android and iphones | Tips and Tricks](http://thetechnoclub.com/featured-articles/install-windows-phone-7-on-android-and-iphones-tips-and-tricks/)

[How to install Windows Phone 7 on HTC HD2? (Video)](http://www.jayceooi.com/2011/01/14/how-to-install-windows-phone-7-on-htc-hd2-video/)

---

To Install **Android on your iOS Devices** (This also possible...)

Look at [How To Install Android on your iOS Devices](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_install_android_your_ios_devices)

[Android 2.2 Froyo running on Iphone](http://thetechnoclub.com/google-ocean/android-google-ocean/install-ios-4-on-htc-android-phones/)

Comment: Can android be installed on samsung focus i917. I am sick of using windows phone, no apps at all

Comment: If your device has a required and capable hardware to run android, then you can..

Comment: How to know if my device has capable hardware ?

Comment: @user370305 what if the installation procedure goes wrong..can we revert back to windows again ????

Answer (score 0):

Android needs to be compiled for every hardware plattform / every device model seperatly with the specific drivers etc.
If you manage to do that you need also break the security arrangements every manufacturer implements to prevent the installation of other software - these are also different between each model / manufacturer.
So it is possible at in theory, but only there :-)